# Migrate from MySQL (MariaDB) to SQL (Azure)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, mariadb, ssms

I'm having trouble with this process, and would love some pointers!

Current source database is a MariaDB one (similar to MySQL). I have ODBC drivers connecting successfully.

I've installed Microsoft SQL Server Management (SSMS) 17, and connected to my Azure SQL Database.

I've found solutions that its possible to create a Linked Server in SSMS - but for some reason I cant see this in my Object Explorer?

I've tried to use the SQL Server 2017 Import and Export Tool.
Selected the source as .Net Framework Data Provider for ODBC, and entered the name of the DSN.

Select the destination as SQL Server Native Client (also tried Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server).

First warning thrown up (not sure if this is an issue?)
*[Source Information]
Cannot locate the mapping file to map the provider types to SSIS types*

And the big error...

### **TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard**

Could not connect source component.

> Error 0xc0047062: Source - tblBookings [1]:
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [42000]
>   [ma-3.0.6][5.5.59-MariaDB]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '"tblBookings"' at line 1    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle,
>   RetCode retcode)    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments,
>   SQL_API odbcApiMethod)    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.DataReaderSourceAdapter.ReinitializeMetaData()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostReinitializeMetaData(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100
>   wrapper)

---

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

> ERROR [42000] [ma-3.0.6][5.5.59-MariaDB]You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '"tblBookings"' at line 1
>   (maodbc.dll)

---

BUTTONS:
OK
------------------------------*

Happy to try and do this migration another way too. 
Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let's see the statement that got that syntax error.

Comment: If you are migrating _to_ MySQL or MariaDB, use MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing this as root user:

```
Set global sql_mode=ansi_quotes
```